# sudo apachectl configtest no funciona

Tags: php, apache

Tengo un website en digital ocean, com LAMP.
El proyecto en local funciona.

cuando lo puse el servidor remoto, y configure el archivo `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
con la ruta del proyecto. pero este comando

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

me tira este error

```
root@genesis:/# sudo apachectl configtest
apache2: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 1 of /var/www/verduleriaGenesis/server.php: 
/var/www/verduleriaGenesis/server.php:1: <?php?><?php?> was not closed.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

y el error que produce se muestra en /var/log/apache2/error.log

> [Fri Sep 21 23:41:59.421793 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5460] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> [Fri Sep 21 23:41:59.572839 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5646] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Fri Sep 21 23:41:59.572965 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5646] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>
> [Fri Sep 21 23:45:15.127800 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5646] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

cuando pongo

```
apachectl restart
```

sale este error

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 1 of /var/www/verduleriaGenesis/server.php: 
/var/www/verduleriaGenesis/server.php:1: <?php?><?php?> was not closed.
Action 'restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

el log de errores, se muestra mas arriba.

El contenido del archivo `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` es

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

El contenido del archivo `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` es

```
    # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
    # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
    # hints.
    #
    #
    # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
    # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
    # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
    # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
    # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
    # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
    # possible.

    # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
    # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
    #
    #       /etc/apache2/
    #       |-- apache2.conf
    #       |       `--  ports.conf
    #       |-- mods-enabled
    #       |       |-- *.load
    #       |       `-- *.conf
    #       |-- conf-enabled
    #       |       `-- *.conf
    #       `-- sites-enabled
    #               `-- *.conf
    #
    #
    # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
    #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
    #   web server.
    #
    # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
    #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
    #   customized anytime.
    #
    # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
    #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
    #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
    #   respectively.
    #
    #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
    #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
    #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
    #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
    # 
    # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
    #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
    #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
    #   work with the default configuration.


    # Global configuration
    #

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.

    #
    # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
    # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
    # at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
    # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
    #
    # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

    #
    # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
    #
    #Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

    #
    # The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
    #

    DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.
    # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    #
    PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

    #
    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 300

    #

    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive On

    # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
    # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
    # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
    #
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    #
    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #

    KeepAliveTimeout 5


    # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

    #
    # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
    # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).


    # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
    # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
    # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
    # nameserver.
    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.

    # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
    #
    LogLevel warn

    # Include module configuration:
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

    # Include list of ports to listen on
    Include ports.conf

    # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
    # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
    # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
    # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
    # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
    # access here, or in any related virtual host.
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>

            AllowOverride None
           Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>

            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #<Directory /srv/>
    #       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #       AllowOverride None
    #       Require all granted
    #</Directory>


    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
    # viewed by Web clients.
    #
    <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
            Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>


    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive.
    #
    # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
    # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
    # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
    # requests.
    #
    # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
    # Use mod_remoteip instead.
    #
    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" $
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combin$
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # Include generic snippets of statements
    IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

    # Include the virtual host configurations:
    IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

    Include /etc/phpmyadmin//apache.conf
```

Comment: cual es el contenido de `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` ?

Comment: Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Comment: @aloMalbarez solo eso.

Comment: cual es la linea 230 del apache.conf?

Comment: @aloMalbarez debajo coloque el contenido del archivo apache2.conf

Comment: @aloMalbarez ya coloque el contenido del archivo, en la pregunta.

Comment: ese parece estar bien (se ve default) el que tiene error parece ser el otro el que se "includea" -> '/etc/phpmyadmin//apache.conf' (yo le pondría una sola / ahi)

Comment: Por qué tu título dice solved?

Comment: @AlfredoPaz porque ya lo resolvi. gracias

Comment: si pero debes añadir la respuesta para que a otros usuarios les sirva @tomasco y no es necesario que le pongas solved, con que añadas tu respuesta y la aceptes queda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El contenido del archivo

```
    # This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
    # the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
    # hints.
    #
    #
    # Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
    # The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
    # upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
    # default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
    # virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
    # order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
    # possible.

    # It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
    # below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
    #
    #       /etc/apache2/
    #       |-- apache2.conf
    #       |       `--  ports.conf
    #       |-- mods-enabled
    #       |       |-- *.load
    #       |       `-- *.conf
    #       |-- conf-enabled
    #       |       `-- *.conf
    #       `-- sites-enabled
    #               `-- *.conf
    #
    #
    # * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
    #   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
    #   web server.
    #
    # * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
    #   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
    #   customized anytime.
    #
    # * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
    #   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
    #   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
    #   respectively.
    #
    #   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
    #   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
    #   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
    #   their respective man pages for detailed information.
    # 
    # * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
    #   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
    #   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
    #   work with the default configuration.


    # Global configuration
    #

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.

    #
    # NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
    # mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
    # at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
    # you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
    #
    # Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
    #
    #ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

    #
    # The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
    #
    #Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

    #
    # The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
    #

    DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

    # PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
    # identification number when it starts.
    # This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    #
    PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

    #
    # Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
    #
    Timeout 300

    #

    # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
    # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
    #
    KeepAlive On

    # MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
    # during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
    # We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
    #
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

    #
    # KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
    # same client on the same connection.
    #

    KeepAliveTimeout 5


    # These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
    User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
    Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

    #
    # HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
    # e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).


    # The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
    # had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
    # each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
    # nameserver.
    #
    HostnameLookups Off

    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.

    # "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
    #
    LogLevel warn

    # Include module configuration:
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
    IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

    # Include list of ports to listen on
    Include ports.conf

    # Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
    # not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
    # The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
    # the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
    # your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
    # access here, or in any related virtual host.
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>

            AllowOverride None
           Require all denied
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/share>
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>

            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #<Directory /srv/>
    #       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #       AllowOverride None
    #       Require all granted
    #</Directory>


    # AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
    # for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
    # directive.
    #
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
    # viewed by Web clients.
    #
    <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
            Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>


    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive.
    #
    # These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
    # (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
    # requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
    # requests.
    #
    # Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
    # Use mod_remoteip instead.
    #
    LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" $
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combin$
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
    LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
    LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

    # Include generic snippets of statements
    IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

    # Include the virtual host configurations:
    IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

    # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

    Include /etc/phpmyadmin//apache.conf
```

Comment: @aloMalbarez ese es el contenido del archivo apache2.conf